# How to scale, rotate and crop an Image

Tags: node.js

I have a client side code which is used to select portion of the user uploaded image. And I am not using Canvas to crop image as I don't want to sell app performance in low end mobiles. Here is the object that app results

```
{ scale: 1.4, angle: 270, x: 10, y: 20, w: 400, h: 400, devicePixelRation : 2 }
```

I am able to rotate, and crop image based on dimensions but would like to know how to scale the image before crop. Thanks. I am using https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine for client side area selection.

Comment: @wintermute You better welcome yourself first :) I am eager to vote myself to close this question by knowing your reason to down vote.

Comment: Check [`gm` image processing module for node.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny tested it, but still its failed to crop exactly.

Comment: How about [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)?

Comment: @Jakeii Could you please add an example. And also I think I need to consider `devicePixelRatio`?

Comment: Do you want to crop on server side with node.js? if so, What is your server running, Windows, Linux or OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how it can be done! use nodeJS gm module and crop like below

```
var newW = imageWidth * body.scale, newH = imageHeight * body.scale;
gm(req.files.file.path)
   .rotate('white', body.angle)
   .resize(newW, newH, '!')
   .crop(body.w, body.h, body.x, body.y).write(path, function(err){

});
```